# Trouble with image in my html page being pushed off center

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

In my HTML page, I have some social media icons at the top of the page, and a logo that's supposed to be in the middle. But, after I added the icons, they're pushing the logo to the side a bit.
[Here's an image of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npfZG.png)

The question mark symbol is supposed to be in the middle of the entire page (directly in between the "updates" and "archive" in the nav bar), but it's being pushed off. Is there a way I can make the logo in the center of the entire page?

In my **HTML** I have:

```
    <img src="https://imgur.com/16OdDvD.png" class="sns-icon" id="ig">
    <img src="https://imgur.com/nQ2aUYu.png" class="sns-icon" id="reddit">
    <div class="center">
        <img src="https://imgur.com/hQRzG5G.png" id="headerlg">
    </div>
```

Then in my **styles.css** I have:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

#headerlg {
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
}

.sns-icon {
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

I've also tried `justify-content: center` and `margin: auto` both of which didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your source code didn't work for me, but here I write some code like yours, I solve your problem with flex box and add some visual style, I hope it's make sense to you.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.container>div {
  width: 33%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>HTML & CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="social-media">
      <span>instagram</span>
      <span>twitter</span>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      icon logo
    </div>
    <div class="put-nothing">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I just created 3 div 1 of them contain social media ,another contain logo , and last one left empty. all of them have same width in all device (mobile, tablet, laptop).